# Robolectric: ShadowApplication?

Tags: android, robolectric

I am seeing a lot of reference to ShadowApplication in some code via stackoverflow and google but i have no idea what it does.

I don't know if i am missing some documentation resources but i can't  feed any good resources, the javadoc api doesn't explain much either.

Can anyone provide further info on ShadowApplication, is there any more resources i.e Training, Tutorials ?

I am sure i am missing a lot more other than ShadowApplication

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to forbid running android code inside JVM instead of Dalvik VM, Google has stripped the classes in the android.jar file and have had all their method bodies replaced with:

> throws new RuntimeException("Stub!");

Generally speaking, Robolectric use shadow objects with view and resource loading to solve this problem.

#### How does shadow objects work?

- Robolectric intercepts the loading of Android classes under test.
- Rewrites the methods bodies of Android classes (using javassist).
- Binds shadow objects to new Android objects.
- The modified Android objects proxy method calls to the shadow objects.
- Shadows back the Android classes. i.e. ShadowImageView backs the ImageView class.
- Method calls to the Android object are proxied to the shadow object's method of the same signature, if it exists.
- Simple implementations giving rudimentary behavior.
- State is recorded so it can be verified in tests.

Check out the keynote [here](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/resources.html) and [this youtube session](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6FWL877txw) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should look at the docs for [Roboelectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/user-guide.html) and see if they explain the concepts you do not understand.

From the manual:

> Sometimes Android classes don’t provide methods to access the state of
>   the Android objects under test. The Robolectric.shadowOf() methods
>   provide reference to the shadow instances representing Android
>   objects, allowing tests to assert on state otherwise not available.

This makes sense to me when I look at the sources for Roboelectric and see shadow implementation of many (if not all) android classes like Application (see [ShadowApplication](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/pivotallabs/robolectric/0.9.5/robolectric-0.9.5-sources.jar!/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/shadows/ShadowApplication.java?format=ok)).

Comment: I find that the comments were not that clear and the test project would probably be my best bet. However, I'm having trouble importing this into Eclipse. But the Application case in the test project doesn't have any methods and I was interested to see an example application of how that would work in Robolectric since all my activities use the Application to access resources.